# git pull does nothing

Tags: git, bitbucket

`Git pull` or `fetch` on my website's server has unexpectedly stopped working.

The password prompt now reads as

```
Password:
```

What I would expect to see is

```
Password for 'https://example-user@bitbucket.org':
```

Whether I enter the right or the wrong password, nothing at all happens... just a new line in the command prompt, no error messages and no pulling new commits.

'`git remote -v`' shows the correct address for origin and as far as I know nothing has changed in the setup of the server that might explain this unexpected behaviour.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: run `git fetch --verbose` to see if it displays any helpful info.

Comment: Same thing results: nothing at all happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would try `git config --list` just to be sure that git is configured correctly. Search for these lines on your output:

```
user.name=Your Name
user.email=yourname@provider.com
```

Comment: Username and email are there and have not changed. Everything else appears as it should be too.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the url under [remote "origin"] from https to git@gitbuh.com in my .git/config file.

e.g.

url = https://github.com/[YOUR_REP_HERE]

to

url = git@github.com:[YOUR_REP_HERE].git